# Consequences of the prime number theorem for the whole Selberg class

Tags: number-theory

I already asked this question on MathOverflow, but since I didn't get any answer, I ask it here. It seems that in a rather recent preprint (November 4th 2013), Yoshikatsu Yashiro proved both the analogue of Mertens' theorem and of the prime number theorem for the whole Selberg class. My question is thus: what are the consequences of this prime number theorem for the Selberg class?
Thanks in advance.